# RAID controller failure...! Can I just pop disks into another controller, same make and model(ish)

Tags: hard-drive, raid, raid-5

My Promise Smartstor DS4600 went pop!
It has 4 drives set up as RAID 5.
I have purchased a second hand Promise Smartstor NS4600, which I beleive uses the same hardware (Just has added network capabilities).
Can I just plug the drives into this new-er unit, in the same order as original configuration?
Or is there something else I need to do?
Cheers,
Russ

Comment: Hardware RAID controllers are tricky. Is this with important data, or lab/test? Replacing same-model controllers are risky enough, due to potential differences in firmware versions, but completely different models will all but guarantee the firmware is different. It may or may not work. Whatever you do, however, do not initialize the array. This will likely wipe the existing array and create a new one in it's place.

Comment: Thanks for that. I think the last firmware was at least 7 years ago, this is listed as a legacy product on Promises website. When you say initialize. Do you mean through the software interface? I was just going to plug the drives in and connect via usb to see if all information is still there. Should I do something else first? Sorry if I'm being a bit dumb...

Comment: It is with important data. I have tried to connect each hard drive individually with an external sata connection, but they can't be read. I am on Mac OSx.

Comment: When I had a hardware RAID controller, I had a separate boot-up menu after the BIOS where I went in to make changes. You need to try to "import" the array, and if it fails, it'll likely ask if you want to "initialize" it. That is the risky part, and if the controller doesn't recognize the array, it will wipe it and create an array it does recognize.